# Faking a variable in an Xpath expression

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In straight XSLT 1.0, it's not possible to use a string variable as an XPath expression.

But if the possible expressions were all simple, like "/book/chapter/verse" or "/year/make/model/style" -- only children axis, just element nodes, no predicates -- is it possible to build a key where the key string is that path? Something like

```
<xsl:key name="elementByPath" match="*" use="path()" />
```

If so, then you could have

```
select=key(elementByPath, $var)
```

where $var could be a string like "/book/chapter/verse".

But straight XSLT 1.0 doesn't have a path() function. :(

It's easy enough to get a path with

```
 <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
      <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

but that can't go in the @use of a key. :(

Is there another way to select elements by a variable XPath expression when the possible expressions (though many) are simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Something can be done**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pPath1" select="'/books/book/title'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pPath2" select="'/books/book/description'"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElemByPath" match="*"
  use="concat('/', name(ancestor-or-self::*[last()])
             ,'/', name(ancestor-or-self::*[last()-1])
             ,'/', name(ancestor-or-self::*[last()-2])
             )"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy-of select="key('kElemByPath', $pPath1)"/>
==========&#xA;<xsl:text/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="key('kElemByPath', $pPath2)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<books>
    <book isbn="1590593049">
        <title>Extending Flash MX 2004</title>
        <description>
        Using javascript alongwith actionscript 3.0 and mxml.</description>
    </book>
    <book isbn="0132149184">
        <title>Java Software Solutions</title>
        <description>
            Complete book full of case studies on business solutions and design concepts while building mission critical
            business applications.
        </description>
    </book>
</books>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<title>Extending Flash MX 2004</title>
<title>Java Software Solutions</title>
==========
<description>
        Using javascript alongwith actionscript 3.0 and mxml.</description>
<description>
            Complete book full of case studies on business solutions and design concepts while building mission critical
            business applications.
        </description>
```

**If you know the maximum number of location steps in a "path", then you can define a key similar to this example**. The expressions with smaller number of location steps must end with the necessary number of slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Or how about **just recursively parsing the string brute-force**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:param name="pPath1" select="'books/book/title'"/>
<xsl:param name="pPath2" select="'books/book/description'"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="elementsByPath">
        <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$pPath1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>==========&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="elementsByPath">
        <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$pPath2" />
    </xsl:call-template>        
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="elementsByPath"> 
    <xsl:param name="path" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($path,'/')">
            <xsl:for-each select="*[name()=substring-before($path,'/')]"> 
                <xsl:call-template name="elementsByPath">
                    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-after($path,'/')" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()=$path]" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." /><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When that transformation is applied to Dimitre's sample XML, the **correct result is obtained**:

```
<title>Extending Flash MX 2004</title>
<title>Java Software Solutions</title>
==========
<description>
        Using javascript alongwith actionscript 3.0 and mxml.
    </description>
<description>
        Complete book full of case studies on business solutions and design concepts while building mission critical
        business applications.
    </description>
```

I think that would work . . .

Comment: Of course this kind of processing isn't new -- I have answered similar questions at least twice. What is new here is the idea/attempt to use a key. And of course, using the `key()` function is much-much faster.